# Django: How to test whether a user is a member of a subclass of django auth Group?

Tags: python, django

I have the following:

```
class Department(Group):
    hod = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False)
    # Other fields
```

and I need to check whether a user is a department member. Do I go:

```
if user.groups.filter(department__pk=department.pk).exists():
    # Do something
```

or:

```
if user.groups.filter(pk=department.pk).exists():
    # Do something
```

or is there a better way to check this?

Thanks

Comment: `if user.groups.filter(department=department).exists()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an check this in a slightly shorter way:

```
if my_user.groups.filter(department=my_department).exists():
    # …
    pass
```

This means that the user belongs to a group with the given *`my_department`*.

If on the other hand you want to if a `user` is the *head of the department* (`hod`), you check this with:

```
if my_department.hod_id == my_user.pk:
    # is head of the department
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, would it make sense to say: my_user.groups.filter(pk=my_department.pk).exists()? In other words, is Department stored as a django auth Group or are they separate (but linked) objects?

Comment: @SiphiweGwebu: normally yes, but this is more an implementation detail on how inheritance is implemented (at the moment), and thus can change.